# hh:mm:ss date format in MDX

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ssas, mdx, analysisservices

**How can I get current date on hour-minutes-seconds (06:13:47) format in MDX?**

I'm trying to create a 'New Calculated Member' on the 'Calculations' Options inside the Cube used.

```
CALCULATE;
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].AverageAnalysisTimeFormatted
AS FORMAT([Measures].[AverageAnalysisTime], "HH:MM:SS"),
VISIBLE = 1 ;
```

My current result inside as it is (without the Calculated Member) is AnalysisTime = 1574,30

Which is 1574 seconds, or 26 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this, I got 00:26:14 on Adventure Works cube:

```
with member measures.AverageAnalysisTime as 1574

member measures.AverageAnalysisTimeFormatted as measures.AverageAnalysisTime / (3600.0 * 24.0)
           ,format_string = 'hh:mm:ss'


           select measures.AverageAnalysisTimeFormatted on 0 from [Adventure Works]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "Now" and "Cstr" function . Take a look at the query below

with member
measures.t 
as 
cstr(datepart("h",Now()))+':'+cstr(datepart("n",Now()))+':'+cstr(datepart("s",Now()))

```
select 
{
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],measures.t 
}
on columns,
[Product].[Category].[Category]
on rows 
from 
[Adventure Works]
```

Result

[image]